# Passing a PHP array via Javascript to another PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I may be going about this the hard way, as I modeled my code after an older article: [populating triple dropdown list](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html) but I have found I don't need to query the database, because all the information is already neatly stored for me in a PHP array used earlier in the script.

I have a PHP array already created ($events):

```
<?php foreach($events as $event) {
```

Now I have to pass the *events* array to another file for processing:

```
<select name="search_month" onChange="getMonth('filter-leaderboard.php?month='+this.value)">
```

I'm just not sure how to pass it via Javascript.

How do I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: Serialize the php array and pass ot to your javascript function, then deserialize it again when needed

Comment: What is in `$events`? What is your `foreach` doing? Your `onchange` event should send the selected value of your select to `filter-leaderboard.php` as `$_GET['month']` but I can't tell much more than that from this question.

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 - $events is an already set and functioning array. The foreach is going through each event and running some statements. This is already existing code that is working fine. I was just showing that to say that I do have an existing *and* functioning array that I could pass and manipulate in my secondary PHP script. I need the month and the extra data in the $events array to create my new options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your question, it appears you're trying to get the month using AJAX?

If so, it'd probably be better to post the array as the body rather than doing a get request.

You can use the json_encode function (https://www.php.net/json_encode) to convert the array into a JSON object so you can work with it in JavaScript.

Comment: Using json_encode was my solution and I was still able to do a get request. However, what do you mean by "post the array as the body"? I'd rather do that if it means better code. Thanks!